# Quotient of group given by presentation is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Consider the group $$G = \langle a,b,c ~ \mid ~ a^2 = b^3 = c^5 = abc \rangle$$
Prove that $\mathbf{(a)}$ $abc$ is an element of the center of $G$; and $\mathbf{(b)}$ $G/ \langle abc \rangle$ is a finite group.

To prove $\mathbf{(a)}$, we can show that $abc$ commutes with the generators $a,b,c$:
$$a(abc) = a(a^2) = a^3 = a^2(a) = abc(a)$$
$$b(abc) = b(b^3) = b^4 = b^3(b) = abc(b)$$
$$c(abc) = c(c^5) = c^6 = c^5(c) = abc(c)$$

But I'm not sure how to prove part $\mathbf{(b)}$... any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting fact: A group given by a presentation of the form $\langle a, b, c; a^i, b^j, c^k, abc\rangle$ is called a [triangle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group#Von_Dyck_groups), and is finite if and only if $1/i+i/j+1/k>1$. Clearly $G/\langle abc\rangle$  has a presentation of this form (but using this classification to answer your problem is somewhat boring). [Wikipedia called these groups "von Dyke groups", but I have never seen them called that in the literature.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the quotient: $abc=1$, which means that $abc=a^2=b^3=c^5=1$.

Using the fact that $c=(ab)^{-1}$, we get that $(ab)^5=1$, meaning that the group is really
$$\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^3=(ab)^5=1 \rangle.$$

the Cayley graph for this group is the [truncated dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_dodecahedron) where $b$ can be seen in the  the triangles, $(ab)$ is identifies with decahedrons and the edges connected them should be understood as two edges, $a^2$. Since the polyhderon is simply connected, this is the Cayley Complex, and hence we deduce that the group is finite. Hence, the group is finite with 60 elements. [it is in fact $A_5$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999312/group-presentation-of-a-5-with-two-generators)

Comment: What you know is that the group is generated by torsion elements. This doesn't imply that every element is torsion; for example, $\langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = 1 \rangle$ is the infinite dihedral group, which contains elements of infinite order such as $ab$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan i did not mean to publish that preliminary answer, sorry.

Comment: The first sentence is still incorrect. You cannot conclude from it that the group is torsion, and most triangle groups aren’t.

Answer (score 0):

$G/<abc>$ is a finite Triangle group. (See Wikipedia for helpful info on these groups).